# Getting an error when trying to remove comma from a freetext column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

```
USE DBname
UPDATE notestable
SET NotesColumn= REPLACE(NotesColumn,',','') 
WHERE NotesColumn LIKE '%,%'
```

when i try execute this code, i'm getting the below error.

```
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.
```

i managed to do similar code a week ago and removed all inverted commas from this column already but there is clearly something i'm missing out. (I changed the names purposely since we work for a government entity)

I'm using the code from this post but its still not working: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12c2e9bf-a5c2-484a-a7b3-021890c61963/how-to-remove-comma-fro-sql-string?forum=transactsql

Comment: what does the data look like?

Comment: @dbajtr it's a notes column for when a nurse writes a short description of what happened to the patient

Comment: May be your field may be of other datatype rather then NVARCHAR? Kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a `REPLACE` on a text data type. Convert it to `[n]varchar(max)` first.

```
USE DBname
UPDATE notestable
SET NotesColumn= REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), NotesColumn),',','') 
WHERE NotesColumn LIKE '%,%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 195837 rows have just been affected :)

Comment: I hope that is what you expected! :)

Comment: I hope it is as we were having a problem getting reports with our reporting software to output to CSV and it was because of special chracaters

Answer (score 1):

Try it maybe problem depends on `text` datatype, convert it to `varchar(max)`

```
USE DBname
UPDATE notestable
SET NotesColumn= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), fieldName),',','') 
WHERE NotesColumn LIKE '%,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE DBname
UPDATE notestable
SET NotesColumn= CAST(REPLACE(CAST(NotesColumn AS nvarchar(MAX)),',','')AS ntext) 
WHERE NotesColumn LIKE '%,%'
```